# Close answer because of "length or low quality"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, flagging

There is the option to vote for a close because of **length or low quality**. What is wrong with answers like [this one](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/8171/2653). It's short but useful therefore not really of low quality. What's wrong with those kind of answers? I think it's OK to give a one-liner if it has new and useful information. Also closing this stuff isn't increasing our multiple-answer-ratio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answers can be useful, yes, but the vast majority really aren't, which is why the close reason exists.

Remember numbers of questions and answers are only one set of metrics. We also need quality.

Comment: I understand that point. We also need quality so if we have lots of questions which just get 5 "one-liner" answers that's not the way we want it. Still most who are around on SX for longer time will provide longer, quality answers. I see no problem to allow some shorter ones like the one I linked to. What do you think for that example?

Comment: So I mean we shouldn't just vote to close inherently because the answer isn't *looking nice* because it's so short.

Comment: The one you linked to seems fine to me. There will be exceptions to every rule on se, probably. You should vote to close because an answer isn't suitable for whatever reason, but if a short answer works, keep it.

Comment: @Rory: *Remember numbers of questions and answers are only one set of metrics. We also need quality.* Exactly!